# Create solution programmatically

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

We are automatically creating solution files (sln) and solution filters (slnf) during our CI.
Since we are not working inside Visual Studio we cannot use the DTE to work with Therefore we are using the Microsoft.Build nuget packages.

Everathing works fine, except that there is not possibility to create a solution file programmatically. It seems that I have to create it fully manually by stiching blocks of text.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's [MvsSln](https://github.com/3F/MvsSln) which is very powerful in editing. Also there's mine little project that has very simple API - bunch of immutable types and [`saveToFile`](https://github.com/jl0pd/LightSolutionConfigurationManager/blob/2669fd48c19b275dc7171fdc55858afe44373ac2/src/LightSolutionConfigurationManager/Types.fs#L233) function

Comment: @JL0PD: Thanks a lot. I think this is what I need.

Comment: @JL0PD, thanks for your shared solution. And it does help to the customer,I suggest you could add an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment helped, posting it as answer

There's [MvsSln](https://github.com/3F/MvsSln) which is very powerful in editing. Also there's mine little project that has very simple API - bunch of immutable types and [`saveToFile`](https://github.com/jl0pd/LightSolutionConfigurationManager/blob/2669fd48c19b275dc7171fdc55858afe44373ac2/src/LightSolutionConfigurationManager/Types.fs#L233) function